# Run dpkg so that it installs dependent packages

Tags: debian, dpkg

I have downloaded a `.deb` file but when I install it, it complains that a bunch of packages are not installed. I am using a very bare bones focal Docker image.

```
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of wkhtmltox:
 wkhtmltox depends on fontconfig; however:
  Package fontconfig is not installed.
 wkhtmltox depends on libfreetype6; however:
  Package libfreetype6 is not installed.
 wkhtmltox depends on libjpeg-turbo8; however:
  Package libjpeg-turbo8 is not installed.
 wkhtmltox depends on libpng16-16; however:
  Package libpng16-16 is not installed.
 wkhtmltox depends on libx11-6; however:
  Package libx11-6 is not installed.
 wkhtmltox depends on libxcb1; however:
  Package libxcb1 is not installed.
 wkhtmltox depends on libxext6; however:
  Package libxext6 is not installed.
 wkhtmltox depends on libxrender1; however:
  Package libxrender1 is not installed.
 wkhtmltox depends on xfonts-75dpi; however:
  Package xfonts-75dpi is not installed.
 wkhtmltox depends on xfonts-base; however:
  Package xfonts-base is not installed.
```

I'm used to software development package managers that normally just go ahead and install dependencies.

How can I make `dpkg` work like that? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can’t make `dpkg` do this; the appropriate tool is `apt`. Instead of

```
dpkg -i /path/to/package.deb
```

use

```
apt install /path/to/package.deb
```